# How to get a list of all attributes in model -Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, list, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get a list of all names,emails and phones without writing similar class with get() method for each of them. Is there a way to write one general class for this purpose?I used APIView and Serializer(instead of ModelSerializer) consciously. Here is my code.

**views.py**

```
class userInfoList(APIView):

def get(self, request, format=None):
    users = userInfo.objects.all()
    serializer = userInfoSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from phonenumber_field.serializerfields import PhoneNumberField
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import userInfo

class userInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=70)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return userInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: why are you overriding the update method?

Comment: @ruddra I didn't include all my code here. I m using put, delete functionalities for each user

Comment: What excatly you are looking for? is your code not working?

Comment: @VineetYadav I just don't want to get each user's all information. I also want to get all emails or all names seperately

Comment: It will be better if you provide a example of response you seek, like what i understand you need is: {data: [{'id':1, 'name': 'u1', 'email': 'email1', 'phone': 'phone1'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'u2', 'email': 'email2', 'phone': 'phone2'}], 'all_emails': ['email1', 'email2'], 'all_names': ['u1', 'u2'], 'all_phone': ['phone1', 'phone2']}. Is that correct?

Comment: @Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generic views in DRF - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

There is a possibility to define a `serializer_class` for a `generic.ListView`, so you could have one base serializer for your model, and three sub-serializers with the fields you are intereseted in:

```py
class BaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=70)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()

    ...

# Here is your sub-serializer
class EmailSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
         fields = ["email"]

# Here is your separate view for retrieving only emails:

class FetchEmailsView(generic.ListView):
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
    queryset = userInfo.objects.all()
```

Comment: I'm getting error like:TemplateDoesNotExist: api/userinfo_list.html

Comment: @mooncake, sorry for misguiding, but I meant the `generics.ListCreateAPIView` module from DRF, not `django.views.generic.ListView` - that's probably why you get the template does not exist error

Comment: 'm not only retrieving emails, and also all other attributes as well. Same result with my get() method.